# How to delete a player structure from memory after deleting it from a container

Tags: arrays, list, go, memory, release

How can I delete a structure from memory and not have it called at all? I need that when I remove it from the List, it is also cleaned from memory and the cycle stops, but it does not stop. Tell me how to do it right, thank you in advance.

```
type Player struct {
    PlayerID int
}

func (p Player) Create() *Player {
    fmt.Println("Create Player:", p.PlayerID)

    go func() {
        for {
            println("test")
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        }
    }()

    return &p
}

func main() {

    playersList := list.New()
    playersList.PushFront(Player{PlayerID: 1}.Create())

    for e := playersList.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        println("Remove Player:", e.Value.(*Player).PlayerID)
        playersList.Remove(e)
        e.Value = nil
        runtime.GC()
    }

    fmt.Scanf("h")
}
```

[log]
Create Player: 1
Remove Player: 1
test
test.
test...

Comment: The program will exit here. https://go.dev/play/p/0XLU_gLVw27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, or at least you need to write the exit strategy manually. When you created a goroutine using `go` keyword, it will allocate a stack in the memory and whatever live in that stack are considered as root objects, and thus won't be garbage collected. It will only be deallocated when the goroutine finished. If gorotine A creates goroutine B, and goroutine A finished, it doesn't automatically stop goroutine B. The only thing can stop goroutine B is the goroutine B itself, either by finishing the goroutine or panic. Although, you can use channel to send a message from goroutine A to goroutine B to tell goroutine B to stop executing, but the logic to stop the goroutine B should be handled inside goroutine B itself.

In your case, if you want to stop the goroutine when removing the `Player`, you need to do it manually. One way is you can use channel. Every `Player` can maintain a channel, and when you remove it from the list, close the channel. Then in your `for` loop inside the goroutine, you need to check if the channel is not closed and break from the loop when the channel is closed. Something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/7wnAO2Xa9PL